# Xamarin Android - Start FragmentActivity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment that has a button click event, on clicking this button i need to start a FragmentActivity, but i seem to be getting errors whichever way i try to do it.

Here is my button click event in the Fragment:

```
myExhibitGallery.Click += delegate {

    //StartActivity(typeof(MyExhibitHistoryActivity));

    Intent intent = new Intent(MyExhibitHistoryActivity);
    StartActivity(intent);
```

As you can see i've tried using two different methods (intent and StartActivity), but both throw errors.

Here is the FragmentActivity i want to start:

```
[Activity (Label = "My Exhibit History")]           
    public class MyExhibitHistoryActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        ViewPager _viewPager;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.MyExhibitHistory);

            _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager> (Resource.Id.viewPager);
        }
    }

    public class ViewFragmentAdapter: FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public ViewFragmentAdapter (Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm) : base (fm)
        {
        }

        public override int Count {
            get { return 5; }
            }



        public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem (int position)
        {
            return new viewerFragment();
        }
    }


    public class viewerFragment: Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {
        public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var view = inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.myExhibitHistoryItem, container, false);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Can anybody show me the correct way to start the FragmentActivity please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a using to your Fragment:

```
using Android.Content;
```

Add a function to handle the event like this:

```
void StartMyExhibitHistoryActivity (object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    var myExhibitHistoryActivity = new Intent (this.Activity, typeof(MyExhibitHistoryActivity));
    StartActivity (MyExhibitHistoryActivity);
}
```

And finally add the Click event:

```
myExhibitGallery.Click += StartMyExhibitHistoryActivity;
```